# configuration section not allowed to be set below application when cloning web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-config

I have the requirement to clone a web app hosted in iis server, so i just copy the folder and tried to set the new app in iis, but i'm getting and error:

"configuration section not allowed to be set below application"

the error line is the windows authentication section.

Comment: Please give more details.

Comment: Are you cloning the app into a sub folder of the original site?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue right clicking in the application folder in ISS and clicking Convert to Application.